# Installing Python libraries to macOS default Python (2.7.10) with pip

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I would like to install some Python libraries to the default Python 2.7.10 which is provided with OSX. Can I do that using pip?

Apparently now pip installs libraries in a different Python path:
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

The reason why I am asking this question is that I am using a program that can only use the built-in Python and that does not support virtualenv.

I have tried with `sudo pip install packageX`, but I get "Requirement already satisfied" and if I run a Python script using the Automator or via /usr/bin/python, I keep getting "ImportError: No module named packageX".

I am running macOS 10.13.2.

Some more details: if I run `type -a python`

I get:

```
python is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

While `which python`
returns:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Comment: Have you tried `which pip`? If it doesn't match `which python`, you might have to call pip using its full path.

Comment: Here is what which pip returns: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip

Answer (score 1):

If you install your library using sudo / root like this:

```
$ sudo pip install <library>
```

You should be able to access it globally. If this doesn't work, please update your question with the error you're getting.

Comment: I get "Requirement already satisfied", but then if I run a Python script using the Automator or via /usr/bin/python, I keep getting "ImportError: No module named ..."

Answer (score 1):

A bit lengthy but you could try calling pip via the full path:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install <module>
```

if this works then can reroute pip call in your bashrc?

Comment: Again, I get `Requirement already satisfied: <module> in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but then, if I run a Python script using the Automator or via /usr/bin/python, I keep getting  `ImportError: No module named packageX`

Comment: there are several pips there in my installation. ie. pip; pip2 and pip2.7 have you tried all three?

Comment: a different hack, you could try to add /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python‌​2.7/site-packages to the python path of the system python? You could quickly test this by just adding a sys.path.append("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python‌​2.7/site-packages") to the beginning of your script?

Comment: If this works you could permanently add that path to your pythonpath.

Comment: I still get some errors:

OSError: Octave Executable not found, please add to path or set"OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE" environment variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163867/discussion-between-user3235916-and-user3352382).